# AWS Windows CHEF client and Hosted CHEF server connectivity

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

We have CHEF windows client running(as a Windows service) in AWS Window 2012 server (old version of chef client is already installed and we don't want to change this chef client)

In hosted CHEF ,we have an organization and using the validator key the above said windows service was created and service is running with local system account.

Now , how this windows CHEF client can be connected with the Hosted CHEF server? Through Bootstrapping process? But bootstrapping again installs chef client which can mess up with the old chef client which are already installed in AWS Windows server.

How to connect this AWS Chef client with hosted CHEF Server? Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a custom bootstrap template that only does the configuration and doesn't try to install anything. That said, it usually doesn't try to reinstall if the client is detected.